# Mechanisms to pass properties to base class

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class

What are the mechanisms to pass properties from the derived class to the base class so that:

- Base ctor can access them.
- They can be easily stored in STL containers.
- Anyone outside can access them, "seeing" only on derived class.
- Effectiveness isn't pretty valuable.

Property is a constant that relates to *every* object of derived class.

Comment: in your code there is no "constant that relates to every object of derived class", hence the connection between the code and the text is not clear. What is wrong with / missing from the code you posted?

Comment: @idclev463035818 The virtual funcs represent constants.

Comment: so the question is how to acces them in the base class constructor? Or what else to use instead of virtual functions?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes

Comment: I cannot follow your arguments against bullet point 3. If you need a value to construct an object then passing it as parameter to the constructor is natural, not "obstructed". If you dont like to have the constructor public you can make it protected. Also this does not "assumes that it's allowed to create base objects with any properties." (at least not more or less as it is the case for any constructor), both the base class and the derived can still check for valid parameter and act accordingly.

Comment: @idclev463035818 When I use the third way, the base class holds the constants, and not the derived. And nobody outside can obtain these values if he has only the derived class.

Comment: You could declare the variables as `protected` in the base class and have the derived class populate them.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "What are the mechanisms to pass properties from derived class to base class?" there are two ways to do that.

1. The very common way is to initialize parent class through *member initializer list*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const char *a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(const char *a)
    : Base{a} { }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d{"Parent initialization through member initializer list"};
    // console output: Parent initialization through member initializer list
}
```

2. Getting constructors inheritance with the *using* keywork

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const char *a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d{"Parent class initialization through constructor inheritance"};
    // console output: Parent class initialization through constructor inheritance
}
```

Look at an useful example with a template class

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class custom_vector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    // I will inherit all std::vector constructors
    using std::vector<T>::vector;
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    // Inizializer list constructor
    custom_vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << std::endl;
    // 1 2 3 4 5
 
    // Fixed-allocation with default value constructor
    custom_vector<char> v2(10, 'A');
    for (auto x : v2) std::cout << x << std::endl;
    // A A A A A A A A A A
}
```

Without **using std::vector<T>::vector** I would not have inherited std::vector constructors.

In your example I notice some design deficiencies

- Virtual functions are not used to pass properties to base classes
- I don't understand why you mentioned templates
- You shouldn't repeat the virtual keyword because it's already virtual in derived class, using override keyword is fine.
- It's generally not recommended to having a partially implemented abstract class, you should consider deleting m_image and m_speed from BaseVehicle. There are cases where having a some implementation in an abstract class is actually useful but only do this if you have a good reason.
- Having a statement like this *table.registerVehicle(*this, number)* in a constructor of an abstract class is a bad design symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it virtually or non-virtually. But to answer which one of these is the best, let's examine your example:

```cpp
class Bicycle: public BaseVehicle
{
public:
    Bicycle(VehicleTable& table, Number number): BaseVehicle(table, number) {}

    virtual float getMaxSpeed() const { return 40.0f; } // constant
    virtual float getWeight()   const { return 10.0f; } // constant
    virtual float getLength()   const { return 2.3f;  } // constant
    virtual int   getWheels()   const { return 2;     } // constant
};
```

Each one of these functions returns a constant but still requires a virtual call to obtain that constant. This is poor practice, because you need to perform an (expensive) virtual call to obtain each of the values.

### Better Approach: Using `struct`

Instead, it would be better to pass these constants to the parent's constructor and store the constants in the base class. This way, you don't need to access the `vtable` of `BaseVehicle` at all and can simply access them directly inside the base class. Like this:

```cpp
struct VehicleStats {
    float maxSpeed;
    float weight;
    float length;
    int wheels;
};

// BaseVehicle's constructor now becomes this:
BaseVehicle(VehicleTable& table, Number number, VehicleStats stats)
```

Alternatively, you could create only one `virtual` function in `BaseVehicle`:

```cpp
virtual VehicleStats getStats() const = 0;
```

This will most certainly be better than creating four separate functions.

### Alternative Approach: Using `enum`

You can also pass an `enum` representing the type of the vehicle to the parent. For example:

```cpp
enum class VehicleType {
    BICYCLE,
    CAR
};

// BaseVehicle's constructor now becomes this:
BaseVehicle(VehicleTable& table, Number number, VehicleType stats)
```

You then store the stats globally:

```cpp
static const std::map<VehicleType, VehicleStats> globalStatsMap;
```

This is a very good approach if you have a large amount of stats and don't want to increase the memory size of the base class. You now also don't need an instance of `BaseVehicle` at all and can still look up properties based on the type.

Answer (score 0):

From what is shown, you don't need inheritance at all:

```
struct VehicleAttributes
{
    float maxSpeed;
    float weight;
    float length;
    int   wheelsCount;
};

class Vehicle
{
private:
    Vehicle(VehicleTable& table, Number number, const VehicleAttributes& attributes): m_image(attributes.length, attributes.wheelsCount), m_attributes(&attributes)
    {
        table.registerVehicle(*this, number);
    }

public:
    static Vehicle BiCycle(VehicleTable& table, Number number)
    {
        static const VehicleAttributes bicycleAttributes{40, 10, 2.3, 2};

        return Vehicle(table, number, bicycleAttributes);
    }
    static Vehicle Car(VehicleTable& table, Number number)
    {
        static const VehicleAttributes carAttributes{88, 42, 2.5, 4};

        return Vehicle(table, number, carAttributes);
    }

    const VehicleAttributes& getAttributes() const { return *m_attributes; }

private:
    Image m_image;
    const VehicleAttributes* m_attributes = nullptr;
    float m_speed = 0; // the current speed
};
```

Comment: This code is pretty broken. You are still calling `getLength()` and `getWheels()` in the initializer list, you misspelled `VehicleAttributes`, you misspelled `vehicleAttributes`, you're not initializing `m_attributes` with an address and you are assigning `nullptr` to it by default even though it's always initialized.

Comment: @J.Schultke: I didn't realize that previous constructor calls the virtual methods. I hope I fix typos (easier to catch with IDE/compiler ;-)). I forgot `&` to take address (typo too :/). I prefer to default  to `nullptr` initialization every pointer/built-in, even if always initialized (easier to debug in case of mistake).